# How to check whether a dropdown value is selected or not in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, angular-ngmodel

How to check whether a dropdown value is selected or not in angularjs?
I dont want to know which value is selected. I Just want to know whether any value from dropdown is selected or not? How can i do that in a simple way. If anyone knows please help.Thanks in advance.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelX}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu " >
    <li ng-repeat="data in A"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>



  <button class="btn" ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelY}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu " >
    <li ng-repeat="data in B"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>



  <button class="btn"  ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelZ}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="data in C"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This is the set of cascading dropdowns i have.. I have to enable the next dropdown ,if anyvalue from previous dropdown is selected.. So i want to know ,is there any simple way to just know whether any value from dropdown is selected or no in angularjs ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check ng-model value for selected item, and trigger ng-change when the model is changed. **[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQORPQuvaI3pJtr1123T?p=preview)** is my plunk to give you the picture.

```
<select ng-model="dd1" ng-change="updateDd2(dd1)" ng-options="o for o in dd1Array">
    <option value="">Hei dd1</option>
</select>
```

From the above snippet, you can see, I define ng-model to html select tag, and add ng-change to trigger if there is a change in model.

```
$scope.updateDd2 = function(val) {
 if (val === '1') {
   $scope.dd2Array = subArray1;
 } else {
   $scope.dd2Array = [];
 }
}
```

Above snippet is triggered when there is a change occured.

Hope it help. Thanks